# How to click Yes on UAC on CMD Admin?

Tags: java, cmd, admin, uac

How can I click the *Yes* button on the cmd-admin mode using Java code?

I just used the code below to automatically opens the cmd admin using the shortcut button (admin enabled):

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
rt.exec("cmd /c start C:/Files/cmd-admin.bat2.lnk");
```

After launching the cmd (admin enabled) it shows a pop-up *User Access Control* that has Yes or No.

How can I code this in Java to select the *Yes* button? By the way I'm using this on automation on a windows 7 64-bit PC.

Comment: I think the whole point of UAC is to *prevent* programs doing things without explicit consent from the user. Why do you need to work around it?

Comment: Cameron Skinner is correct. UAC is explicitly designed to prevent this. UAC would be pointless if you could programmatically bypass it. The "what if this were possible" thought experiment is helpful: If it were possible, this is precisely what all malware would do.

Comment: UAC cannot be bypassed programmatically, it is supposed to be the user and the user alone who can consent. The only tip I have is that a program which has already been elevated can continue to spawn elevated processes, only triggering the UAC prompt once. It is generally a bad idea to create programs that always run elevated unnecessarily however, as any security vulnerabilities instantly become much more severe, and I think it is probably good practice to trigger the UAC prompt on every elevated action instead. It also has the benefit of keeping the user better informed.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is: You cannot bypass the UAC prompt. Read the following blog posting for the many reasons why:

[FAQ: Why can’t I bypass the UAC prompt?](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-blog-archive/faq-why-can-8217-t-i-bypass-the-uac-prompt/ba-p/701510)

Quoting from that FAQ:

> The designers of Windows Vista's User Account Control expressly decided not to incorporate functionality like setuid/suid or sudo found in Unix and Unix-like OSes such as Mac OS X. I think they made the right decision.
>
> ...
>
> If it were possible to mark an application to run with silently-elevated privileges, what would become of all those apps out there with LUA bugs? Answer: they'd all be marked to silently elevate. How would future software for Windows be written? Answer: To silently elevate. Nobody would actually fix their apps, and end-user applications will continue to require and run with full administrative permissions unnecessarily.